# Run javascript function only for one time (first page load)

Tags: javascript, browser, modal-dialog

I'd like to run this javascript function only for one time (first page load). Is it possible? Thank you

```
<div id="pag">
<script type="text/javascript">

var framekiller = true;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
if (framekiller) {
    return "Click on stay on this page";
}
};

</script>

<iframe scr="http://www.example.com/page-with-javascript-framebuster.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying first page load? you dont want it on a second reload?

Comment: I mean that the function run only for one time and if I click on a link in the page where the script is, the dialog doesn't show up again

Comment: did you mean you want this function to lounch dialog on load but not on exit?

Comment: Yes but the page frames another page that has framebuster. It is considered an exit?

Answer (score 0):

You should use global variables in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.framekiller = true;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
if (window.framekiller) {
    return "Click on stay on this page";
}
};

</script>

<iframe scr="http://www.example.com/page-with-javascript-framebuster.html"></iframe>
```

And put somewhere else, another javascript snipper, who turn this variable into false, and do other things.. eg opens a new link?
To turn it back to false, use:

```
window.framekiller = false;
```

Comment: Now the page does the following things: The page load, the iframe contained in the "pag" starts loading, a javascript alertdialog appears, if the user clicks on stay on this page the iframe and the rest of the page finish to load. At this point I want the function disabled if possible.

Comment: So the user clicks on something? On the onClick callback, set the variable to false, using the line of code I provided in the second code block!

Comment: I don't know what the onclick callback is. I have to study javascript first if you don't provide the complete code i should add

Comment: No, when I say click on links after the iframe loads I mean that the user have to be free to click on all the other links on the page and to close the browser window, go back etc. I had to put this javascript alert only to avoid the redirection caused by a frame buster cointained in iframe in my page